# Angular authentication wait to set permissions in local storage before guard

Tags: angular, authentication, wait, guard

I try to implement an authentication service in my project.
A backend provide me a sso token and the current user permissions.

```
{
    "success":true,
    "data: [
            {
             "first_name":"Michel",
             "last_name":"Drucker",
             "email":"mdrucker@fr3.com",
             "company":"fr3",
             "image":"http://micheldrucker.com/moi.jpg",
             "permissions":["ADMIN"]
            }
           ]
}
```

I want to set in local storage those data, but my guard doesn't wait for those data to be set. 
So my verification in guard doesn't work, I have an error 
`Cannot read property 'data' of null`.

To prevent this error, I set an item permissions, before treatment like `localStorage.setItem('permissions', 'xxx');`

**app.component.ts**

saves the token that comes from the url with an event snapshot

```js
this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
            // put sso and permissions in local storage
            if (event instanceof ChildActivationStart) {
                if (event.snapshot.queryParams.sso !== undefined) {
                    localStorage.setItem('sso', event.snapshot.queryParams.sso);
                    this.apiService.permissions().subscribe((data) => {
                        localStorage.setItem('permissions', data.data[0].permissions);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

**authorization.guard.ts**

check route permissions rules, block user if is not authorized

```js
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        // declaration of route roles path
        const allowedRoles = next.data.permissions.only;
        // check if user is authorized
        const isAuthorized = this.authorizationService.isAuthorized(allowedRoles);

        if (!isAuthorized) {
            this.snackbarMessage.openErrorSnackBar(this.translate.instant('GUARD.UNAUTHORIZED'));
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }

        return isAuthorized;
    }
```

**authorization.service.ts**

control the user

```js
isAuthorized(allowedRoles: string[]): boolean {
        // check if the list of allowed roles is empty, if empty, user can access
        if (allowedRoles == null || allowedRoles.length === 0) {
            return true;
        }
        // get permissions stored at app init after login
        const permissions = localStorage.getItem('permissions');

        // if it's not exists, delete sso token and go back to login
        if (!permissions) {
           localStorage.removeItem('sso');
           this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }

        // check if user has route allowed roles
        const rolesIsFound = allowedRoles.filter(element => permissions.includes(element));

        let userAuthorized = false;

        if (rolesIsFound.length > 0) {
            userAuthorized = true;
        }

        return userAuthorized;
    }
```

**route.ts**

```
{
        path: '',
        component: FuseHomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard],
        data: {
            permissions: {
                only: ['ADMIN'],
            }
        }
    },
```

**auth-interceptor.ts**

```
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const sso = localStorage.getItem('sso');
        if (sso) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-API-KEY': sso,
                }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request).pipe( tap(() => {},
            (err: any) => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    if (err.status !== 401) {
                        return;
                    }
                    localStorage.removeItem('sso');
                    localStorage.removeItem('permissions');
                    this.snackbarMessage.openErrorSnackBar(this.translate.instant('GUARD.UNAUTHORIZED'));
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                }
            }));
    }
```

I don't think my code is very good, store the data in the app component don't seems to be good. By setting the permissions 'xxx' users can access see the app a few seconds until the http response forbid the user. I think this is just a "waiting" problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `authorization.service.ts` to return boolean observable instead of boolean then your `authorization.guard.ts` will wait till the observable is resolved.
Also you can move the code to clear SSO token from localstorage to an interceptor whenever you get 401 HTTP status.

**authorization.service.ts**

```
isAuthorized(allowedRoles: string[]): Observable<boolean> { 

 return new Observable(observer => {
    const permissions = localStorage.getItem('permissions');
    if (!permissions) {
        this.apiService.permissions().subscribe((data) => {
            const permissions = data.data[0].permissions;
            localStorage.setItem('permissions', permissions);
            observer.next(this.hasValidRole(permissions));
            observer.complete();
        });
    } else {
        observer.next(this.hasValidRole(permissions));
        observer.complete();
    }
  });
}


hasValidRole(permissions) {
    // check if user has route allowed roles
   const rolesIsFound = allowedRoles.filter(element => permissions.includes(element));

   let userAuthorized = false;

   if (rolesIsFound.length > 0) {
     userAuthorized = true;
   }

   return userAuthorized;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I also have an interceptor, it catch 401 response from API. I was wondering if it's better to get the sso in the url inside the interceptor instead of in my app component ?

Comment: If you are call an endpoint explicitly to fetch SSO token then no need to fetch it in interceptor. Keep only the logic that can happen on any request inside an interceptor, like if your backend automatically refreshes the token on any HTTP request then you can have the code to fetch the SSO in interceptor.

Comment: I'm still stuck with Cannot read property 'data' of null at line 19 of authorization.service. 
It looks like the api call this.apiService.permissions() doesn't work anymore

Comment: I think this ```Cannot read property 'data' of null``` is because of my interceptor, where I put headers : 
```const sso = localStorage.getItem('sso');
        if (sso) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-API-KEY': sso,
                }
            });
        }``` 

I don't know ..